# Can I ‘equate coefficients’ in dot product?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Say I have $\vec a$ a nonzero vector. After calculations for a question, I have that, for any $\vec u$,$\vec v$,

$$\vec u \cdot \vec v=\lvert\vec a\rvert^2(\vec u\cdot\vec v)+\beta(\vec a \cdot \vec u)+\alpha(\vec a \cdot \vec v)$$

Can I then effectively equate coefficients and say $\lvert a\rvert=1, \alpha=\beta=0$?

Comment: You can use some properties of scalar product, such as distributivity and the rule for scalar multiplication to obtain another form of the right side, i think.

Comment: In principle yes, but more directly set $v=0$, $u=a$ to find $β=0$, then $u=0$, $v=a$ to find $α=0$, etc.

Comment: @LutzL that's a great shout

Comment: To give an elementary illustration of LutzL's approach: Suppose I tell you that $\vec a\cdot \vec x = 0$ for all vectors $\vec x$. How do you deduce that $\vec a$ must equal $\vec 0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin by picking three standard basis vectors in turn?

Comment: There's a better choice ... that doesn't depend on coordinates (or finite dimensions!].

Comment: @TedShifrin can I do $\vec a \cdot \vec a$?

Comment: There you go! Judicious choice of $\vec x$.